# Is there a way to use starred expression dynamically?

Tags: python

I have a function that takes *args as parameters. I also have a list.

Based on a condition, I either want to pass the list to the function or unpack the list using starred expression in the function call.

I have to call this function and pass the list, unpacked or not, many times. But the condition determining wether the list needs to be unpacked or not only needs to be evaluated once at the start.

I would like to avoid writing many if statement checks to evaluate the condition only just to determine if I need * or not. Is there a way to do this dynamically? Or is there a better way of doing this that I am not thinking of? I wish I could apply the logic within the function but unfortunately I cannot modify the function.

Here are some examples of what I've tried but failed:

```
if condition:
    parameters = *list
else:
    parameters = list

...
func(parameters)
...
func(parameters)
...
func(parameters)
...
```

```
if condition:
    parameters = '*list'
else:
    parameters = 'list'

...
func(parameters)
...
func(parameters)
...
func(parameters)
...
```

edit: added more func calls to be clearer.

Comment: No there isn't. Either move the function call inside the if-statement or reuse the conditions

Comment: Have you tried `if condition: func(*params); else: func(params)`?

Comment: I don't know your specific use-case, but wouldn't `parameters = *list` and `parameters = list` behave  the same?

Comment: @SayandipDutta I don't think so. In fact `parameters = *list` will not even work.

Comment: Yeah, I meant `parameters = *list,` of course, otherwise it doesn't make sense. Only difference would be `*` would create `tuple` of elements, instead of `list` of elements.

Comment: @Chris Yes, ternary would work the same as if blocks but I'm trying to avoid repeating the condition checks.

Comment: inside the function they should function the exact same

Comment: "Chris" doesn't talk about ternary operator. Pay attention to colons and semicolon. It's just the same as "sshashank124" said. What issues with that solution do you have?

Comment: @mrEvgenX Sorry I don't follow or maybe I'm not clear. My code example above only calls the function once (for simplicity) but I actually need to call it many times in my use-case. I'm trying to avoid the same condition check every time I call the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other way around from what you're doing: you can't "unpack" a list into a variable, that makes no sense, however you can wrap a parameter into a list and always unpack it.

That is:

```py
if condition:
    parameters = list
else:
    parameters = [list]

...
func(*parameters)
...
func(*parameters)
...
func(*parameters)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use lambdas:

```
if condition:
    new_func = lambda params: func(*params)
else:
    new_func = lambda params: func(params)
...
new_func(parameters)
new_func(parameters)
new_func(parameters)
```

Comment: You could even avoid the trampoline by straight by defining `new_func  = func` and only wrapping it in a lambda if the condition is true.